# Material UI: Cannot read property 'button' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeOptions } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = (options: ThemeOptions) => {
    return createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            primary: {
                main: '#b5ddd1'
            },
            secondary: {
                main: '#b2d9ea'
            },
        },
        typography: {
            fontFamily: 'Raleway, Arial',
            button: {
                fontStyle: 'italic',
            },
        },
        ...options,
    })
}
```

provider

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

         <Provider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <GlobalStyles/>
                    {/*<ErrorBoundary>*/}
                    {/*<Layout>*/}
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                    {/*</Layout>*/}
                    {/*</ErrorBoundary>*/}
                </ThemeProvider>
            </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
```

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'

            <div>
                <div>Log into APP</div>
                <Button>Test</Button>
            </div>
```

But I am still getting error in Button.js

at styles (/Users/filipbrezina/Documents/Projekty/sportee-frontend/node_modules/
material-ui/core/Button/Button.js:33:78

Can someone help me please? I don't know what am I doing wrong

Comment: Can you please add codesandbox URL so that we can help you debug the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in the way you are defining / providing the [`theme`](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/):

You need to provide it like this:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme({})}> {/* function call: theme({}) */}
```

Or if you define it like this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#b5ddd1',
    },
    // you can add more options
  }
})
```

you can provide it this way:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
```